# Python gives me one and minus one, how can I change that to True and False?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I tried boolean but it gives True to everything, I am using Ubuntu Virtualbox, installing Python 3 in it.

Answer (score 2):

```
def change(that):
    if that == 1:
        return True
    else if that == -1:
        return False
    else:
        raise ValueError("That is not -1 or 1 as expected.")
```

then you can call

```
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    my_list[i] = change(my_list[i])
```

Comment: All fine, except `change` is a terrible name for that function.

Comment: you mean `ValueError`. Python != Java

Comment: @zvone It reflects OP's own target name for this function (specified in the title). I'm just fulfilling specified task conditions.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Very true, a google search has misled me. Fixed